# Class project: user-editing page for a haiku website

Tags: beginner, html, css

I am making a website using just HTML and CSS for a classroom project (we are in the 2nd week of boot-camp.) I have my site made, and want to get others' opinion on the code. I am mostly looking to have the site scale properly on different browsers, but other input is appreciated as well.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
}

.top {
    background-color: #F25266;
    border: #666561 solid 1em;
}

h1 {
    color:#F4EF6B;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}

.middle {
    background-color:#ECECEC;
    border-left: #666561 1em  solid;
    border-right: #666561 1em solid;
}

.pic {
   display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}


form > label{
    color: #2E90BF;
    column-count: 1
}


form > input {
    background-color: #2E90BF;
    border-color: #666561;
    width: 14.2%;
    column-count: 1
}

#button_one {
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    background: #2E90BF;
    border-color: #000;
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

#button_one:active {
  background-color: #2E90BF;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.bottom {
    background-color:#F25266;
    border: #666561 solid 1em;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    column-count: 10;
}


a:link {
    color: #6DBF2E;
}

a:visited {
    color: #6DBF2E;
}

a:hover { 
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit User</title>
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Link to CSS Sheet -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body background>
    <div class="top">
        <h1 style>User Information</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/57/7b/3c/577b3c221b6ebdc218c347d1260a102e--japanese-haiku-poetry-lessons.jpg" alt="Haiku Example Pic" class="pic"/>
        <form>
            <label>E-Mail:</label>
            <input>
            <label>Password: </label>
            <input>
            <label>Confirm Password: </label>
            <input>
            <label>First Name: </label>
            <input>
            <label>Last Name: </label>
            <input>
            </br>
            <button type="submit" id="button_one">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="form_create_haiku.html"><span>Create Haiku</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="form_edit_haiku.html">Edit Haiku</a></li>
            <li><a href="form_edit_user.html">Edit User</a></li>
            <li><a href="form_signup_user.html">Signup User</a></li>
            <li><a href="haiku_list.html">List</a></li>
            <li><a href="haiku_one.html">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="haiku_rules.html">Rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="user_list.html">User List</a></li>
            <li><a href="user_one.html">User One</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About the HTML

It’s typically a good idea to add a `meta`-`charset` element, which [gives the character encoding](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#specifying-the-documents-character-encoding) of the page (e.g., "UTF-8"). This should be the first element in the `head` element:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- … -->
</head>
```

The `body` element can’t have a `background` attribute ([it’s obsolete](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/obsolete.html#element-attrdef-body-background)).

You should associate each `label` with its `input`. This can be done with the [`for` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-label-for) or by nesting the `input` inside the `label`. You can easily test if it works correctly: click the label, and the corresponding `input` should get the focus.

You have the closing tag `</br>`, but miss the opening tag -- however, the `br` element has no closing tag to begin with, so you probably want to use `<br>` or `<br />`. But it doesn’t seem to be correct to use `br` in this context anyway. `br` must [only be used for meaningful line-breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32277267/1591669). If you just need some vertical space, use CSS instead.

The list seems to be navigation. If that’s the case, you could use the `nav` element:

```html
<nav class="bottom">
  <ul>
    <!-- … -->
  </ul>
</nav>
```